# Extending application or using singletion?

Tags: java, android, singleton

I have an android project where i have different objects that one or more of my activities need to acess now i was thinking of creating a subclass of `Application` however under the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) of Application it states the following:

> There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way. If your singleton needs a global context (for example to register broadcast receivers), the function to retrieve it can be given a Context which internally uses Context.getApplicationContext() when first constructing the singleton.

My question is fairly simple is it best pratice to use a static singleton class to contain all of your objects ? or am i right to assume that extending application is a better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question I would use a singleton container to access these objects, initialize that class with a context by application context (there are very big chances you will need a Context); but then you will see it's kind of hard to maintain these and the singleton container.

To solve this object graph issue, I would use some IoC: [RoboJuice](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice), [AndroidAnnotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations) or [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/) are really cool and they provide much more. Each of them handles this issue different, but you don't have to worry about that.

I hope it helps!

Comment: I'd go with pure Guice (I never liked the idea of being forced to extend a RoboActivity or similar). And if you like Vie winjection you could go for Butterknife (https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife)

Comment: To my understanding current RoboJuice version doesn't force you to extend RoboActivity, as it is driven by annotations. The problem with RoboJuice is that it is so poorly documented. One has to read its source code in order to understand how to use it.