# Static variable in Application subclass. (Android)

Tags: android

Is there any point in having a static variable in a subclass of Application in an android app.
If I understand things correctly, the Application is a singleton that's instantiated when the app is started and its public variables will be global.
If I declare a variable as "public static" in the Application subclass, am I just pointlessly making a variable global that would have been global anyway?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`If I understand things correctly, the Application is a singleton that's instantiated when the app is started` 
Yes, it is a singleton from OS point of view maybe, but not from yours unless you implement it - make a static reference in your class and provide a static method `getInstance()`. 
 
`and its public variables will be global` 
True, but only only static variables will be accessed directly. You will need to provide the `getInstance()` method in order to get the non-static instance and only then you'll have access to class public declared variables. So far nothing new from Java and OOP point of view. 
`If I declare a variable as "public static" in the Application subclass, am I just pointlessly making a variable global that would have been global anyway?`
Yes, you can very well have these defined anywhere else.

To add more: you shouldn't care that much about getting an instance of the `Application` class anyway as it seems a bad practice. An `Application` has its own meaning and logic and getting a reference to it is dangerous and pointless at the same time.

May seem related to [another similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16972545/1051783)

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply @gunar. However I still don't fully get it. Here's my question in another way. If I extend application with "MyApp extends Application", and add a "public String myString" to it, then I can access myString globally and since there's only one copy of MyApp there is only one copy of MyString ever created. From what I can see a static variable is also accessible globally and there's only one copy of it.

Comment: Here's the full version...Thanks for the speedy reply @gunar. However I still don't fully get it. Here's my question in another way. If I extend Application with "MyApp" and add a "public String myString" to it, then I can access myString globally and since there's only one copy of MyApp there is only one copy of MyString ever created. If I create a static myString it's also accessible globally and there's only one copy of it. Is there any reason for using a static myString inside MyApp when all of it's public methods already seem to do the same thing (performance, readability, etc.)??Thanks